# What is "Audio data"

Tags: deezer

I am building a web game which is going to use tracks' preview from deezer API. To be able to get a preview URL I need to query Deezer API with the track's ID - e.g. http://developers.deezer.com/api/explorer?url=track/3135556

So in order to be able to query the API, I need to store tracks' IDs in the DB.

However when I read http://developers.deezer.com/guidelines there's paragraph in the end:

*Local Storage/Offline Storage policy
Important Local Storage/Offline Storage of audio data is strictly forbidden. If in some cases you need to optimize your application and store audio data, please contact Deezer.*

I am curios what to imagine under "audio data". Does storing track's id violate this restriction or is it fine?

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more legal than technical, and "audio data" is vague enough for potentially erroneous answers to be posted and get you in trouble. Get in touch with Deezer or consult a lawyer.

Comment: I understand this question may not be technical but on their support page - http://developers.deezer.com/support - there's written to email them only for advertising or commercial use, so I am trying to get answer from them this way if it is their prefered way...

Comment: They're not following [the recommendations for product support on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253852/99692), then — SO should not be the only support option, and there especially needs to be provision for questions that are off-topic on SO.